User is not being redirected to teams custom app in iOS after successful authentication
We have developed one custom app for Microsoft Teams that uses an external provider for authentication.
The authentication mechanism has been implemented as per the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-oauth-provider
The authentication with external provider is working fine when we try to use the App inside Desktop Teams, Web Teams and Android Teams App. The users is getting authenticated in the browser and being redirected to Custom App .
Here is the code block:
//If using web teams app 
if (method === "page") {
            
      app.initialize().then(() => {
        app.getContext().then(async (context) => {
          authentication.notifySuccess(result!);
        })
      });
} 
// If using desktop, Android or iOS teams app
else if (method === "deeplink") {
     
      var encodedWebUrl = encodeURIComponent(`${window.location.origin}`);
      var encodedContext = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"subEntityId": result}));
      var deepLinkUrl = `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${authId}/dashboard?webUrl=${encodedWebUrl}&context=${encodedContext}`;
        
      window.location.href = deepLinkUrl;

      //window.location.href = `msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/auth-callback?authId=${authId}&result=${result}`
} 
else {
    alert("failed");
}

Problem:
If we try to use the custom app inside iOS Teams App, then the user is not being redirected to the custom app instance from where the request is getting generating upon successful authentication.
On redirection, the custom app is being opened inside the popup.
Steps:

Opening App in iOS Teams Login page in our custom app 

Clicking on Login button which redirects the user to external provider in browser (Identity Provider in Popup)

On successful authentication, the user is not being redirected to the main app. Instead of this the App is getting opened in the popup (Landing page after login).


Any help on this would be appreciated
I was looking for some documentation which we can use for our reference but did not find anything.

We have tried to repro this issue. We have raised the bug internally. Thanks!!

@Dinesh-MSFT thank you. May I know how can I track this issue? As MS Partner Center team has blocked our publication due to this issue.
